# Discrepancy between Java, Javascript and PHP for formatting same UNIX timestamp

Tags: php, datetime

```
Date time zone: Asia/Kolkata.
Time Stamp: 1448620722807.
```

***Below scripts have been executed on the same system.***

**Java Code**

```
System.out.println(new Date(1448620722807L)); //Fri Nov 27 10:38:42 GMT 2015
```

**JavaScript Code**

```
console.log(new Date(1448620722807)); //Fri Nov 27 2015 16:08:42 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
```

**PHP Code:**

```
//date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Calcutta");
date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Kolkata");
echo date_default_timezone_get(). '<br/>'; // Asia/Kolkata
echo date('d-m-Y h:i:s:A',1448620722807); // 22-07-2008 09:57:35:PM
```

Java and JavaScript gives the expected results. Am I missing something for PHP?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Javascript (and apparently Java as well, I don't know) handle timestamps as ***milliseconds***, while PHP uses ***seconds***. The correct value for PHP is `1448620722807 / 1000` for the same timestamp.